# Kindle Fire : in full screen mode the menu bar appears when launching a dialogfragment

Tags: android, kindle-fire

I have an `Activity` which is displayed in full screen mode (using `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`). When I launch a `DialogFragment` from this `Activity` the kindle menu appears, how to keep it hidden ?

I have tried fullscreen flags as https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/screen-layout.html#StatusSoft

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your DialogFragment class:

```
@Override
public Dialog getDialog()
{
    Dialog dialog = super.getDialog();
    dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    return dialog;
}
```